# calling recursive function when passing a functon for higher order function

Tags: ocaml, higher-order-functions

I want to recursively call higher order function. so I have a list and I'm passing this list to a function name funcName. but I need to pass a function. and I want to put a logic there. i want to check if the element is eric. how do I recursive function for fun i-> syntax?

```
let aaa c : bool = 
      let rec helper c =
        match c with 
        |element(i) -> funcName (fun i->if (List.hd i)=eric then true else 
                             //now i want to recursively call List.tl inside this inner function
      in
      helper c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking how to call a function recursively when it's defined as a `fun`, which is nameless.

There are ways to do this, but they are more complicated than is worth it (in my opinion).

You can just give a name to the nameless function:

```
let aaa c : bool =
    let rec helper c =
        let rec helper_helper i =
            if List.hd i = eric then true
            else (* Do your recursive calling of helper_helper *)
        in
        match c with
        | Element i -> funcName helper_helper
    in
    helper c
```

Comment: thank you very much. but I have a following question. so inside else bracket I want to add false. then call recursive function on List.tl i. I'm just having trouble where to put List.tl. Would you mind giving me some advice?

Comment: I'm getting Wrong exception (Failure "hd")

Comment: Well you can only call `List.hd` if you know the list is non-empty. If you don't know this, it's probably better to use a `match`. (Or you can use `if` to test for a non-empty list.)